# Error after .NET 3.5 -> 4.5.1 Migration VS2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I'm getting the following error when I try to build my project in VS:

```
  The type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext' is defined in an assembly 
  that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 
  'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[token]'.
```

Inside my Web.config for this solution:

```
    <assemblies>    
      <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[token]"/>
    </assemblies>
```

When I right click on the solution and go to "add reference" the "System.Data.Entity" checkbox is unchecked, however if I check it and then click "OK" and reopen the add reference menu it remains unchecked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say at one point in time in the past, the Entity Framework team took ownership of certain .NET assemblies that THEY now ship vs. waiting for each new .NET version to ship new features. Try upgrading your Entity Framework version or install it through NuGet to see if that fixes your issue.